# Month doesn't change to next one in the uri when month is 0 or January in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date

I'm working on a js function to change the view of a list of leads for a web app I'm working on but I have the next problem, this is my code:

```
// Variables to store actual view month and year
let currentMonthIndex, currentYear;

// This function reads the url and define the actual view month and year
function initCurrentMonthAndYear() {
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const from = urlParams.get('from');
    const to = urlParams.get('to');

    if (!from || !to) { // If this parameters are not defined in the actual url it will declare that we are in the present month
        const today = new Date();
        currentMonthIndex = today.getMonth();
        currentYear = today.getFullYear();
    } else { //If they're defined 
        const fromDate = getMonthAndYearFromDate(from);
        const toDate = getMonthAndYearFromDate(to);

        currentMonthIndex = fromDate.month;
        currentYear = fromDate.year;
    }
}


function formatDate(date) {
    const year = date.getFullYear();
    const month = String(date.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
    const day = String(date.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
    return `${year}-${month}-${day}`;
}

initCurrentMonthAndYear();

// In this section we define the functions for the navigation buttons

function getNextMonth() {

    currentMonthIndex++;

    if (currentMonthIndex > 11) {
        currentMonthIndex = 0;
        currentYear++;
    }

    const nextMonthFirstDay = new Date(currentYear, currentMonthIndex, 1);
    const nextMonthLastDay = new Date(currentYear, currentMonthIndex + 1, 0);

    const from = formatDate(nextMonthFirstDay);
    const to = formatDate(nextMonthLastDay);

    updateURI(from, to);
}

// Update URI reload the view with the url with parameters from and to that correspond to next or previous month


function updateURI(from, to) {
    const url = `${page_url}&from=${from}&to=${to}`;

    window.location.href = url;
}
```

When testing the `getNextMonth()` function using `console.log`, I observe that the months increment correctly, going one by one. The code retrieves the current date range from the URI, for example: 'http://myapp.test/orders/leads/?&from=2023-07-01&to=2023-07-31', and based on that, it adjusts the date range to move one month forward or backward. However, I encounter an issue when the function reaches January. While the 'console.log' shows that it is working correctly, the problem arises when passing the 'from' and 'to' parameters back to the `updateURI()` function. It gets stuck on January, regardless of the year. This peculiar behavior only happens when the function reaches January. For instance, if I press the 'getPreviousMonth' button and reach January ('http://myapp.test/orders/leads/?&from=2023-01-01&to=2023-01-31'), then attempt to go to the Next month again by clicking the button, the same URI is loaded again ('http://myapp.test/orders/leads/?&from=2023-01-01&to=2023-01-31'). However, when pressing the 'Previous Month' button, it correctly goes to the last month of the previous year.

Can somebody help me to know why this happens?

Thanks.

I tried to test the `updateURI` function with a `console.log` to see what values of the month it receives from the `getNextMonth()` function, but I noticed that it shows the same values as the current month in the view.

Comment: Programming note: just because `from` or `to` are defined does not mean they're dates. Remember to check the result of `new Date`, because [it may return an `Invalid Date` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#return_value). It won't throw.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. I changed `updateURI()` to just log `url` instead of redirecting, and it worked as expected.

Comment: You don't need to manually increment the year if the month goes beyond 11, the *Date* object will handle that. Just do `nextMonthFirstDay = new Date(currentYear, currentMonthIndex + 1, 1)` and delete the `if (currentMonthIndex > 11) {...}` block. You're already relying on this behaviour for December when you set `nextMonthLastDay`. ;-)

Comment: Thank you all guys, After tried @RobG solution I got this fixed, the **if** condition was the problem. :)